# How to Display Data in a single view from Multiple Tables in MVC using Entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to display the the password and user name in the user view
could any one help me?  I created a `User`and `LogIn` table as shown below. How do I display properties from both the `User` and `LogIn` table in my Razor view.

**Models**

```
public class User
{          
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string JobTittle { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }    
}

public class LogIn 
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

    public int LoginID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required.")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public  User User { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    private CodingContext db = new CodingContext();

    // GET: Users
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model Coding.Models.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Sign Up</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: display password... that should never be a thing.

Comment: Anyways, are you using razor views or any front-end frameworks?

Comment: yes razor views i'ts created by default when i create controller

Comment: There is a lot of information missing in this question.  You should post your Controller code and your Razor view code.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Display-Multiple-Tables-In-A-Single-View-In-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is to create a viewmodel that includes both the `User` and `LogIn` objects.  But the quick and dirty method is to just use `ViewBag`s.

```
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    private CodingContext db = new CodingContext();

    // GET: Users
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.User = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserID == someId);
        ViewBag.LogIn = db.LogIns.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LoginID == someId);

        return View();
    }
}
```

You can then use those `ViewBag`s in your view

```
<div>
    ViewBag.User.UserID
    ViewBag.LogIn.LoginID
</div>
```

I would advise you to never store passwords in plain text.  They should be salted and hashed and never displayed.  In addition, I do not know why you would go and create your own LogIn table.  You should look into Microsoft Identity.

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel can have multiple entities or objects from different data models or data source.

useful link:https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/826417/Advantages-of-ViewModel-in-MVC-Model-View-Controll

**Example of ViewModel:**  As per your requirement

```
public class userloginviewmodel
{
     public user users{get;set;}
     public login logins{get;set;}
}
```

**Controller code:**

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
       userloginviewmodel OBJuserloginviewmodel = new userloginviewmodel();
        OBJuserloginviewmodel .Users = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserID == someId);
        OBJuserloginviewmodel .logins = db.LogIns.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LoginID == someId);

        return View(OBJuserloginviewmodel );
    }
```

**viewCode:**

```
    @model Coding.Models.userloginviewmodel

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    }

    <h2>Sign Up</h2>


    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">

            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user.name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.user.name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user.name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>


<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Login.LoginId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Login.LoginId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Login.LoginId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        </div>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>

    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    }
```

**Additional Note** : By using the viewmodel we can achieve most of things we want, even in this, if you want list of users and logins you can just have two more properties in the same viewmodel and get  the result.

Hope the above was helpful

Thanks

Karthik